# Changing ternary expressions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In Python I can do something like:

```python
a = 1 if x==2 else 2 if x==3 else 3 if ... # Like a SQL CASE statement
```

Is there a similar way to do this in JavaScript? Currently I'm chaining ternary expressions together:

```
a = (x===2)? 1 : (x===3)? 2 : ...
```

Is this the suggested way to accomplish that?

Comment: For this specific example, a `switch... case` statement would be more readable. Or a lookup object.

Comment: The chained ternary in JavaScript is exactly equivalent to the nested `x if c else ...` in Python — and almost equally unreadable. (I would argue the condition coming first like in JavaScript is a bit better than Python's idiosyncratic syntax, but that is subjective, I suppose). You can fix it up a little by formatting it in multiple lines, but as Robby says, for the use case you demonstrated here (equality comparison of single variable to constants) better alternatives exist in both languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two alternatives come to mind.

#### `switch`/`case` statement

This doesn't exist in Python, but in JavaScript you can use a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement as follows:

```js
const x = 3;
let a;


switch (x) {
  case 2:
    a = 1;
    break;
  case 3:
    a = 2;
    break;
  default:
    a = 1;
}

console.log(a);

<!-- -->
```

It's a little verbose, but you can get rid of some of the verbosity by wrapping it in a function:

```js
function val(x) {
  switch (x) {
    case 2:
      return 3
    case 3:
      return 2;
    default:
      return 1;
  }
}

const x = 3;
const a = val(x);

console.log(a);
```

#### Lookup object

You can populate an object with lookup values. You can use a regular object, but since you're dealing with numeric keys, a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is more suited:

```js
const values = new Map([
  [2, 1],
  [3, 2]
]);

const x = 3;
const a = values.get(x);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be talking about expressions - the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Here is the example.

The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands: a condition followed by a question mark (?), and then an expression to execute if the condition is truthy, followed by a colon (:), and finally the expression to execute if the condition is false. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the *if* statement.

```
function fun(var) {
  return (var ? '2' : '10');
}

console.log(fun(true));
// Expected output: "2"

console.log(fun(false));
// Expected output: "10"

console.log(fun(null));
// Expected output: "10"
```